# How to create mysql event on amazon RDS mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I want to create mysql event on Amazon RDS mysql instance which contains a stored procedure call like this-

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_archive
                        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
                        STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
                        DO
                        call procedureArchive(250000,7,"day");
```

procedureArchive is a stored procedure I want to create on Amazon RDS mysql instance. DB user have all privileges.Is there any extra configuration required to create event and stored procedure on Amazon RDS?

Comment: *Is there any extra modification required to create event and stored procedure on Amazon RDS?* I doubt. PS. For single-statement procedure BEGIN-END block is excess and can be removed.

Comment: Is there any extra configuration required to create event and stored procedure on Amazon RDS? I want to know whether event and procedure will create same as local mysql server on amazon RDS

Comment: I have no RDS account... simply test, it's more fast then to ask and to wait for an answer.